# Handling timeout when pop up of angular is displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session-timeout

I have an AngularJS app.

I would like to handle errors when the session is timeout. When it is occured i send the user to the login page. 
It is always work for me except when a user clicks on button that opens a dialog box.

I created ErrorService in order to handle this case:

```
app.service('ErrorService', ['$modal', 'AlertService',
    function ($modal, AlertService) {
        this.handleError = function(error) {

        //session timeout
        if ((error.data !== "" || error.data !== null) && 
            (error.status === 403)) {
              window.location.href = "/webapps/";
        } else {
           if (error.data !== "" || error.data !== null)
               AlertService.alert("status: " + error.data);//this will show the actual error thrown from the server if exist, if not exist it will show the http error text
           else
               AlertService.alert("status: " + error.statusText);
       }
    };

}]);
```

In my app i have the next code when i click on a button:

```
  this.sendMessageToAssignedUnits = function (size) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'Screen.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: size
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (response) {
           var simpleTextMessage = "Yo yo";

            $http.post(response.url, simpleTextMessage)
                 .then(function (response) {

                 }, function (error) {
                    ErrorService.handleError(error);
                 }
            );
        }, function () {
            console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };
```

I do not able to go to ErrorService in this case. 
I go to the login page but the background looks like in previous...

Comment: so what is the problem, modal not going away or the redirect to login??

Comment: The modal is opened and inside there is the login page... I would like to see only the login page without the modal... or to go directly to the login page...

Comment: Depending what you are using to create the modal dialog, think of the dialog as a separate window. So when your session expires, it expires in the dialog. As part of the error handling, you should first close the dialog and then change the window.location. You could investigate broad-casting an event, and having a route that the app redirects to when the session expires.